# Getting error 13 while building app using TideSDK developer in MAC OS

Tags: macos, tidesdk

Getting error 13 while building app using TideSDK developer in MAC OS.

I am getting the below error while launching app in TideSDK Developer app in MAC

```
File "/Users/MitrMedia/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/tidebuilder.py", line 143, in
```

app.stage(path.join(options.destination, app.name), bundle=bundle, no_install=no_install, js_obfuscate=options.js_obfuscate, ignore_patterns=options.ignore_patterns)
File "/Users/MitrMedia/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/osx_app.py", line 76, in stage
'-out', p.join(lproj_dir, 'tidesdk.icns')
File "/Users/MitrMedia/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/env.py", line 156, in run
subprocess.call(args)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in **init**
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: @trojanfoe, you can refer this http://www.tidesdk.org/